# Can't load package: package chaincode/chaincode_example02

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm getting the error bellow after try to instantiate a chaincode:

```
2018-03-28 12:51:27.568 UTC [util] DockerBuild -> DEBU 3b2 Attempting build with image hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.0.6
2018-03-28 12:51:28.418 UTC [chaincode-platform] func1 -> ERRO 3b3 Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "can't load package: package chaincode/chaincode_example02: cannot find package "chaincode/chaincode_example02" in any of:
    /opt/go/src/chaincode/chaincode_example02 (from $GOROOT)
    /chaincode/input/src/chaincode/chaincode_example02 (from $GOPATH)
    /opt/gopath/src/chaincode/chaincode_example02
```

Well, previous operations such as `channel create`, `channel join` and `chaincode install` were succeeded or there's no error messages on logs at least. I'm running all commands from cli container and the chaincode exists on PATH mentioned.

Can someone please tell me exactly what's happening?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mount the chaincode folder in docker-compose-cli.yaml properly.

In volume section, check the path of chain code.

In my case, the chaincode folder is located in `/home/b/fabric-samples/chaincode`

So I mounted it like this in volume

```
- /home/b/fabric-samples/chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
```